# Operation `kittens.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new guy and I am trying to make schema and trying to add new data to the schema and I have tried every possible solutions but that didn't work out for me..

Here is my **app.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/db_name',
() => {
console.log("Connected")
});

const kittySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: String
});
kittySchema.methods.speak = function speak() {
var greeting = "My name is " + this.name

console.log(greeting);
};

const Kitten = mongoose.model('Kitten', kittySchema);
var akitty = new Kitten({ name: 'Akashkitty' });

akitty.save();
akitty.speak();
```

**ERROR**

```
C:\Backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:151
      const err = new MongooseError(message);
                  ^

MongooseError: Operation `kittens.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb- 
native\collection.js:151:23)       
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have run your code and got the desired result as it should print. The result I have got is below - [image]

I think you should delete the node_modules and reinstall mongoose and other npm directories with `npm i` and that should solve your issue I hope so.

Comment: I want to ask u something , it takes very time to establish a connection